# PHP/Javascript - passing a date string to AJAX via POST not working

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am creating a simple form that is to post data to a MySQL. Your thinking why POST and not GET? well there is a description field in this form that allows for many characters, and given that GET has its character limitations I opted to use POST.

Without further adieu, Here is my HTML form.

```
<form name="addExperienceForm" id="addExperienceForm" style="display:none;">
                    Title:<input type="text" name="title" id="title" />
                    From:<input type="text" name="startDate" id="startDate" />
                    To:<input type="text" name="endDate" id="endDate" />
                    Description:<textarea type="message" name="description" id="description"></textarea>
                    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="addUserExp()"/>
 </form>
```

here is the jQuery Datepicker code for the date boxes in the form:

```
//allow a date range to be selected
        $("#startDate").datepicker({
                    changeMonth : true,
                    changeYear : true,
                    dateFormat : "M,yy",
        })
        $("#endDate").datepicker({
                    changeMonth : true,
                    changeYear : true, 
                    dateFormat : "M,yy",
        })
```

This is the AJAX function call:

```
function addUserExp(){
        var title = document.getElementById('title').value;
        var startDate = document.getElementById('startDate').value;
        var endDate = document.getElementById('endDate').value;
        var description = document.getElementById('description').value;
        var str = "title="+title+"start="+startDate+"end="+endDate+"desc="+description;
        var req = getXMLHTTP();

        if(req){

            req.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {                        
                        document.getElementById('addNewExp').innerHTML=req.responseText;    


                    } else {
                        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        req.open("post", "addExperience.php", true);
        req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        req.send(str);
    }
```

I suspect the problem is in the AJAX call, possibly something to do with my 'str' variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested your code, but shouldn't str be:

```
 var str = "title="+title+"&start="+startDate+"&end="+endDate+"&desc="+description;
```

Answer (score 0):

After countless hours of reviewing my code, i finally realized that my PHP code was where the problem was.

BEFORE:

```
   <?php


$title = $_POST['title'];
$startDate = $_POST['startDate'];
$endDate = $_POST['endDate'];
$description = $_POST['desc'];

echo $title;
echo $startDate;
echo $endDate;
echo $description;

?>
```

and AFTER:

```
    <?php


$title = $_POST['title'];
$startDate = $_POST['start'];
$endDate = $_POST['end'];
$description = $_POST['desc'];

echo $title;
echo $startDate;
echo $endDate;
echo $description;

?>
```

Notice the $post variables were not reflecting my JS string.

thanks to all who assisted.

Answer (score -1):

It would be much easier to use jQuery to handle AJAX requests:

```
function addUserExp(){
        var title = document.getElementById('title').value;
        var startDate = document.getElementById('startDate').value;
        var endDate = document.getElementById('endDate').value;
        var description = document.getElementById('description').value;
        $.post("addExperience.php", { "title": title, "start": startDate, "end": endDate, "desc":description })
        .done(function(data) {
            document.getElementById('addNewExp').innerHTML=data; 
        })
        .fail(function() { 
            alert("There was a problem with request."); 
        });         
    }
```

You can read more about $.post [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Comment: -1 I think answers like you should use jQuery instead of plain JS to ** insert any JavaScript task here ** should at least be discouraged. There is nothing wrong with plain JS. Furthermore, it's an opinion, not a solution nor it's a diagnosis of the original problem.

Comment: @gregory90 - appreciate the feedback however this did not work. although i agree that jquery would be easier to use, the same problem persists. the title and description are being passed but the date is not.

Comment: @LimH. I've never said that he *should* use jQuery. Of course - there's nothing wrong with plain JS. There's also nothing wrong with using jQuery. It is possible solution and I thought he might be interested in it. After all he's already using some jQuery in his code.

massimorai I've tried this jQuery solution on localhost and works perfectly fine. All data is passed. Jimzie solution is also working.  It seems you've got some errors in your php code.

Comment: @massimorai - I've just copied your code. In my php file I'm using *echo* to return passed data - just to check if it's working. Date looks like: "Feb,2013".

Comment: very strange - for whatever reason, my PHP file is able to get the contents of TITLE, and DESCRIPTION but not the dates. I am baffled.